# Which approach is better for list and grid view of a result set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using materializecss framework to show a set of results. I am trying to implement list and grid view on the results using jquery with onchange event. I have done it in two ways. Just want to know which approach is better or is there any better way to do it.

```js
/* List Grid Switcher 
$('.list-grid-selector').on('change',function(){
 if($(this).val() == "list"){
  $(".project-list").find(".l3").removeClass('l3').addClass("l6");
  $(".project-list").find(".m3").removeClass('m3').addClass("m6");
 }else{
  $(".project-list").find(".l6").removeClass('l6').addClass("l3");
  $(".project-list").find(".m6").removeClass('m6').addClass("m3");
 }
}); */

/* List Grid Switcher */
$('.list-grid-selector').on('change', function() {
  $(".project-list").find(".l3").toggleClass("l6");
  $(".project-list").find(".m3").toggleClass("m6");
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="input-field">
    <select class="browser-default list-grid-selector">
      <option value="grid">Grid View</option>
      <option value="list">List View</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="project-list">
      <div class="col l12 m12 s12" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">first</div>
        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">second</div>
        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">third</div>
        <div class="col s12 m3 l3">fourth</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to go with some plugins where you can include templates on demands. like for grid view just write different template and for list also write different template. and include that on demand of user.
This will save you when you want to add different functionality to specific view.
and your code will be manageable.

here's link for plugin : https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template check this one and make call on.

Comment: Thank you for responding with a better way of doing it but can i know whatever i have done which one is better to use?

Comment: so in 1st approach you are removing l3 or l6 class and adding  l6 or l3 class. but in 2nd method l3 class is not being removed so might be it will have some bad impact. so i would prefer to go with method 1 where code is big but readable and will work correctly.